# app.askForSignIn(); not working at all

Tags: javascript, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, api-ai, dialogflow-es

Sign in intent doesn't work at the moment as clearly explained in the docs, it's just something you can use for test in the emulator, but it's not available in production.

My case is I'm using account linking and my token expires after one day, so if the user doesn't interact with the assistant, the token will no longer be valid. Then if the token is proved as invalid on the webhook I want to send back 'please link your account again' to the assistant from the webhook.

There is a method `app.askForSignIn();` which seems similar to what I need but it looks like it is not available for Dialogflow and only available for the SDK.

So what I have done is:

- Make an intent in Dialogflow with the name `actions.intent.SIGN_IN` and added `actions_intent_SIGN_IN` event to it
- When any request comes to the webhook I check the token, then if I encounter an invalid token I call `app.askForSignIn();`

What is happening:

- The app just left the conversation e.g: test app left the conversation
- When I say again "talk to test app" it is behaving like the account is linked and does not ask for account linking until I manually reset the whole app using the reset button from test console

**Update:**

I tried to use the code snippet from the doc (https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejs/AssistantApp#askForSignIn)
and it is not working as well, here is the response from the simulator when I call `app.askForSignIn();` from the webhook

[image]

Comment: I'm confused by your question. Everything is working but the token expires after one day?

Comment: yes token expires after 1 hour
e.g: i start with the assistant app by saying 'talk to test app', it ask for account linking then i enter password and get in, and let say i command `ok google ask my test app to show me attendance`, and it returns with `4 are present out of ` and all things work fine for one hour, but after one hour token expires and when and when i say `ok google ask my test app to show me attendance` it fails, assistant didnt understand that i'm no more authenticated, and continue with the same token and in result never unlink the account

Comment: In your question, it sounds like you are trying to work around using askForSignIn() ... why is that? askForSignIn() will work from within your web hook called from DialogFlow.

Answer (score 0):

You can have 2 tokens, one being the access token, which is short-lived, and the other being the refresh token which is long-lived.

So, When Google needs to call one of your service's APIs, Google uses these endpoints together to get permission from your users to call these APIs on their behalf. A typical OAuth 2.0 session initiated by Google has the following flow:

First, Google opens your authorization endpoint in the user's browser. The user signs in if not signed in already, and grants Google permission to access their data with your API if they haven't already granted permission.

Then, your service creates an authorization code and returns it to Google by redirecting the user's browser back to Google with the authorization code attached to the request.

Next, Google sends the authorization code to your token exchange endpoint, which verifies the authenticity of the code and returns an access token and a refresh token. The access token is a short-lived token that your service accepts as credentials to access APIs. The refresh token is a long-lived token that Google can store and use to acquire new access tokens when they expire.

Finally, Google calls your service's APIs, attaching the access token with each request. Your service verifies that the access token grants Google authorization to access the API, then completes the API call.